# Magento - display image label on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, click

Not sure if anyone can assit me but I have a product view page and at the top I have the product name in a h1 tag.

Each product has a selection of images attached to it that have the labels as their colour, i.e back, ivory, burgandy etc etc.

I want the Product name to be displayed as follows:

Products Name | Colour

I have managed to get it to happen for the first (defualt) image.

So when you go to the product page the name is:

Albany | Black (exactly as i want it)

I now want when you click on the different colour options (which are images) for the product name to change to:

Albany | Ivory
Albany | Burgandy 
Albany | Chocolate etc etc etc.

I have received a certain amount of help but now I am stuck.

I have been advised to change the script.js file fo the theme to inclide the following:

```
$('.more-views a').click(function(){
$('#label').text( $('img', this).attr('alt')  ); });
```

The code I have surrounding my h1 tag is as follows:

```
<div class="product-name">
            <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>
            <span id="label"><?php echo ' | ' ?><?php echo $_product->getData('image_label');?></span></h1>
         </div>
```

If anyone has any idea how I can achieve this I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

The link to the page in question is here:

http://dansiop.com/yarwood/index.php/albany.html

Comment: I see that the `HTML` of `img` tag is corrupted, the `alt` attribute of all images contains no value. Please inspect element and see. Your code can work if the generated `HTML` is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got several Javascript libraries loaded into the page (including scriptaculous, prototype and jQuery). Seeing that you're not using `jQuery.noConflict()`, you're going to have to use `jQuery` instead of `$` if you're set on using jQuery.

Also, you have jQuery 1.7+ loaded, so I'd suggest you handle this using a delegate.

```
// don't forget document ready
jQuery(function ($) {

    // let's cache the label
    var _label = $('#label');

    $('.more-views').on('click', 'a img', function () {
        _label.text($(this).attr('alt'));
    });

});
```

As mentioned, you have to put in an `alt` attribute in your images for this to work. It doesn't make much sense to get the `alt` value and display that if there's nothing to begin with.

```
<img src="" alt="Blue" />
```

Comment: Thanks man, The only think I had to do with fix my alt code - it was wrong and so the alt code wasnt being echo'd. once i fixed the alt code so that it was echoing it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.more-views a').click(function(){
   $('#label').text( $(this).find('img').attr('alt') );
});
```

Please see my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081138/magento-display-image-label-on-click/#comment14506689_11081138) before this answer.